# How to make a mouse click softer?

Tags: mouse, mouse-click

I have a Razer Diamondback 3G mouse, whose buttons are very sturdy to click. They make a lot of noise and require a lot of pressure to be pressed.

I thought about disassembling it, which isn't a problem at all, but I have no idea what to do inside of it to make it click easier.

I think any mouse works on the same principle when it comes to the two main buttons, so this question could be related to any mouse.

Comment: I don't know the Diamondback at all, but I'd be wary of opening it up to change the click sensitivity. Why not return it and get a softer-click mouse?

Comment: I have the same problem with a Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse. I hope it will improve in time. BTW, I wish I could build a Frankenmouse, gliding over fabric mouse pads like the Microsoft mouse and clicking soft and gentle like the Logitech M110 mouse.

Answer (score 2):

With a mouse with long buttons that go from the middle to the end with the cord, you can just press closer to the edge with the cord, and you have more leverage, so it takes less force.